# Play 2.4.x how use Messages and not MessagesApi I18N

Tags: scala, playframework, internationalization, playframework-2.4

I've done a little bit different form the internationalization guide, at the [play I18N guide](http://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaI18N)

I forced the result to the language in the query string, it works, but it needs to be done in the "correct way". 
It's a good form to keep the work and look for better approach later:

NOTE: I USED THE "MessagesApi" to make it happen.

please see the code below:

```
package controllers
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.i18n.I18nSupport
import play.api.i18n.Messages.Implicits._
import play.api.i18n.MessagesApi
import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.i18n.Lang
import play.api.i18n._
class Application  @Inject() ( val messagesApi: MessagesApi) extends   Controller with I18nSupport {

def index = Action {  implicit request =>
            request.getQueryString("lang") match{
        case Some(lang) =>  messagesApi.setLang(Ok(views.html.index()(messagesApi,Lang(lang))),Lang(lang))
        case None => messagesApi.setLang(Ok(views.html.index()(messagesApi,Lang("en"))),Lang("en"))
    }
}}
```

index.scala.html

```
 @()(implicit message: MessagesApi ,l: Lang)
 <li><a href="./?lang=en"><img src="@routes.Assets.versioned("images/BR.png")" /></a></li>
 <li><a href="./?lang=en"><img src="@routes.Assets.versioned("images/US.gif")" /></a></li>
 <header>
    <h1>@message("intro")</h1>
 </header>
    <p>@Html(message("description"))</p>
```

conf/application.conf

```
 play.i18n.langs = [ "en", "pt","fr" ]
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: What's the best way to do dat? it's too hardcoded

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you mix in the `I18nSupport` trait into your controller then you have an [implicit conversion](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/5d7adcbc246323310f6c9a9ef26555902e0ba3dc/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/i18n/I18nSupport.scala#L26) in scope which translates a `RequestHeader` into a `Messages` instance. If you look into the `request2Messages` method then you can see that it calls the `MessagesApi.preferred(request: RequestHeader)` method.

So in your case you must create a subclass of `DefaultMessagesApi` and override the [MessagesApi.preferred](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/457f74a9a427785876a80a51c0a4c018d0f86865/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/i18n/Messages.scala#L481) method to retrieve the `Lang` from query string as currently implemented in your controller. Then you can bind your instance to the `MessagesApi` trait, so that it gets automatically injected.

To bind your instance you should create your own `I18nModule` similar to the [default](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/457f74a9a427785876a80a51c0a4c018d0f86865/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/i18n/Messages.scala#L561) one provided by Play.

**Note**: For Guice Injection only because it's the default method used by Play. For compile time DI you must follow [another approach](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaCompileTimeDependencyInjection#Using-other-components).

```
package modules

import play.api.i18n._
import play.api.{Configuration, Environment}
import play.api.inject.Module

class I18nModule extends Module {
  def bindings(environment: Environment, configuration: Configuration) = {
    Seq(
      bind[Langs].to[DefaultLangs],
      bind[MessagesApi].to[YourMessagesApi]
    )
  }
}
```

Then you must disable the default Play `I18nModule` module and enable yours.

```
play.modules.disabled += "play.api.i18n.I18nModule"
play.modules.enabled += "modules.I18nModule"
```

Now in your template you must only pass the implicit `Messages` instance.

```
 @()(implicit messages: Messages)
```