# Play 2.5.18 application using Java MessagesApi causing Unexpected exception ExceptionInInitializerError: null error

Tags: java, playframework

I am attempting to move my application from 2.5.12 to 2.5.18, and then onto 2.6.x. I am using the MessagesApi since I read that the old Message is (being) deprecated.

I found this post, but since it is Scala, it did not help me:

[Play 2.4.x how use Messages and not MessagesApi I18N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32382289/play-2-4-x-how-use-messages-and-not-messagesapi-i18n)

I have a controller, Application.java which I have set up the MessagesApi and Messages objects and receive no errors in compiling, but receive this error when attempting to run the application:

```
[error] application -

! @77h0ppgdc - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[ExceptionInInitializerError: null]
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.$anonfun$get$3(DevServerStart.scala:187)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.$anonfun$get$2(DevServerStart.scala:133)
        at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:247)
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.$anonfun$get$1(DevServerStart.scala:131)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$.$anonfun$apply$1(Future.scala:655)
        at scala.util.Success.$anonfun$map$1(Try.scala:251)
        at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:209)
        at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$map$1(Future.scala:289)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:29)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
        at controllers.Application$$FastClassByGuice$$b5b6aa19.newInstance(<generated>)
        at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$FastClassProxy.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:89)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:111)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:90)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:268)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:110)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:90)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:268)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at controllers.Application.<clinit>(Application.java:75)
        at controllers.Application$$FastClassByGuice$$b5b6aa19.newInstance(<generated>)
        at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$FastClassProxy.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:89)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:111)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:90)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:268)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:110)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:90)
```

The line that I am looking at:

```
at controllers.Application.<clinit>(Application.java:75)
```

Here is the snippet:

```
import play.i18n.Lang;
import play.i18n.Messages;
import play.i18n.MessagesApi;

public class Application extends Controller {

    @Inject
    MailerClient mailerClient;

    @Inject
    FormFactory formFactory;

    @Inject
    static MessagesApi messagesApi;

    static Collection<Lang> candidates = Collections.singletonList(new Lang(Locale.US));
    static Messages messages = messagesApi.preferred(candidates);
    ...
}
```

where in the Application.java controller is:

```
static Messages messages = messagesApi.preferred(candidates);
```

I built the code based on this document:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaI18N#Externalizing-messages

I am not sure how to tackle this one. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know how Guice works, but isn't it supposed to inject instances only?

In other words, do you really need `static` fields? I would remove all the above `static` modifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Frederic A. !  I updated my code to read:

```
public class Application extends Controller {

    private final MailerClient mailerClient;
    private final FormFactory formFactory;
    private final MessagesApi messagesApi;

    private final Collection<Lang> candidates;
    private final Messages messages;

    @Inject
    public Application(MailerClient mailerClient, FormFactory formFactory, MessagesApi messagesApi) {
        this.mailerClient = mailerClient;
        this.formFactory = formFactory;
        this.messagesApi = messagesApi;

        this.candidates = Collections.singletonList(new Lang(Locale.US));
        this.messages = messagesApi.preferred(candidates);
    }
...
}
```

The application now runs.